# links moving on click, strangest thing i've seen (in CSS)

Tags: css, hyperlink

Check out my header navigation, looks ok, but when you click on it, it moves?
http://www.indachi.co.id/
Any clue why?
all the code valid and supplied below
HTML

Here is some screenshot:

Before Clicked

[image: Before click]

After Clicked

[image: After Click]

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper-header">
        <div id="logo" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location='../'"></div>
  <div id="wrapper-menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="../" class="current"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 54px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="66" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">home</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="chair/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 45px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="61" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">chair</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="desk/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 43px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="56" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">desk</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="partition/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 80px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="91" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">partition</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="classic/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 58px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="72" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">classic</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="executive_series/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 93px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="112" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">executive </span></span><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 52px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="67" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">series</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="safe/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 37px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="49" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">safe</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="lounge/"><span class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 65px; height: 22px;"><canvas width="77" height="22" style="top: 0px; left: -1px;"></canvas><span class="cufon-alt">lounge</span></span></a>  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      <div id="wrapper-search">
        <form action="search.php" method="get" name="search" id="search">
          <input id="search" type="text" name="search" value="search here" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)">
          <input id="btn-search-submit" type="button">
        </form>
  </div>
      <div class="shadow-down"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper-header{
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
height: 150px;}

.logo{
background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
width: 460px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: -2px;}

.wrapper-menu{
position: absolute;
top: 90px;
left: 8px;
width: 780px;}

,ul.menu{
margin: 11px 0px 0px;}
ul.menu li{
float:left;
height: 26px;
background: url("../img/menu-sep.png") right center no-repeat;
padding: 8px 0 4px 0;}

.ul.menu li.last{
background: none;}

.ul.menu li a{
height: 18px;
padding: 4px 10px 6px;
font-size: 22px;}

.ul.menu li.last a{
color: #466180;}

.ul.menu li.last a:hover, ul.menu li.last a.current{
color: #000033;}

.ul.menu li a:hover, ul.menu li a.current{
color: #000033;}

.#wrapper-search{
background: transparent url("../img/search.png") no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
width: 212px;
right: -2px;}

.#search{
background: transparent;
width: 192px;
height: 25px;
border: 0px;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0 5px 0 5px;}

.#btn-search-submit{
background: transparent url("../img/btn-search.png");
background-position: -30px 0;
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
border: 0px;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
cursor: pointer;}

.#btn-search-submit:hover{
background-position: 0 0;}
```

Comment: "this account has been suspended" re your website link.

Comment: (1) Please stop using floats, use a combination of positioning and display properties instead, and (2) please don't use the * selector, as this is very inefficient in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

This part of CSS is causing this issue:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Since you have `canvas` inside the links. Once it is focussed the above css is applied. Hence it changes the complete layout. I don't think you need any of the above CSS. However you can remove "position:absolute" and still use the above css.

Comment: lot of thanks! i removed that part completely and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`ul.menu li{}` and `ul.menu li a{}` should be `position: relative;`

Comment: well, that almost resolved the problem. but it still moves a little bit when clicked.